# Different colors for folds and subfolds in Vim

Tags: vim, folding

Is it possible to have different set of colors for folds and subfolds, eg:

- blue foreground on grey background for fold level 1 (default)
- black foreground on dark yellow background for fold level 2
- etc... (although going further down would seem a bit excessive)

Answer (score 7):

It depends if you are using Gui Vim version or text one.
From my side (text version) I have set that in my .vimrc

```
hi Folded ctermfg=Black
hi Folded ctermbg=DarkGrey
```

Comment: And for those in the crowd that are pedantic about their rc file, `hi` is short for `highlight`. I find that using the long form works better for when I inevitably don't come back to my vimrc for long periods of time.

Answer (score 6):

From vim documentation:

```
COLORS                          *fold-colors*

The colors of a closed fold are set with the Folded group |hl-Folded|.  The
colors of the fold column are set with the FoldColumn group |hl-FoldColumn|.
Example to set the colors: >

        :highlight Folded guibg=grey guifg=blue
        :highlight FoldColumn guibg=darkgrey guifg=white
```

so you cannot easily do this. The best piece of advice I could give you is to set statusbar to display the current fold level if possible.

Comment: I had seen that... but had not quite grasped the consequences. Thanks

Comment: @ThG those do not color fold column by levels. it's just to set color for whole column.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple patch to the Vim c code that lets you set this up pretty easily.  Let me know if you want the patch to recompile Vim, or if you're on Windows I can send you a patched executable for Vim 7.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to say it was for manual folding of plain text files. Thanks anyway. ThG

Comment: In this case, why not remap zf to also do a :call matchadd() and zd to do a `:call matchdelete()`?

Comment: Benoit : I did not know this function and looked it up in the documentation. How do you, in that case, define the pattern ? More generally, how do you define in that function a pattern such as : FROM the beginning of the line TO a sequence of characters such as, eg, -:- ? (Could be used in a list of definitions to highlight the word to explain : Vim -:- an exacting text editor...) ThG

Comment: @ThG -- I think my patch would work for manual folds also.  It involves using the 'foldexpr' option to set up function that returns the fold text.  In the function you are able to change the highlight, and I believe the v:foldlevel variable is available to use to decide what highlight to apply, even for manual folding.  If you have any interest I could confirm that.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz : I have interest, but alas little competence. Anyhow, I am ready to try ... (Mac OS Terminal, Vim 7.3). As they (approx.) say in Mission impossible : "As always, should I fail in my mission, you may disavow any knowledge of my actions"

Comment: @ThG -- I did check and it does work with manual folding, but it sounds like you may have problems patching and recompiling Vim on OSX.  If not, I'll be happy to give you the code.  The coloring isn't exactly a trifle to me, since writing outlines is most of what I use Vim for, but it may not be worth it for you.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz : I think my level in Vim is just not quite up to the task, yet. BTW it is not a trifling question for me either : in fact I wanted to manage a sort of personal Vim cookbook (items and definitions), with folds and subfolds, always opened during my Vim sessions, as an emergency toolkit... Thanks again

Comment: @HerbertSitz could you host source of patch on github? that would be nice. if you do - leave a reply here.

Comment: @Amis -- The patch to Vim is included in the 'contrib' directory of my VimOrganizer project on github:  https://github.com/hsitz/VimOrganizer   To use it you have to include code in the foldexpr function to change what highlighting group is used.  You could look at sample in the org.vim file in ftplugin directory.  (That example also uses special feature of specifying different highlight for first word only, as well as for entire folded heading.)